# How to show tags in php?

Tags: php

```
<ul>
  <?php
     $value = "<script>...</script>,<?php>...</?>,<&>...</&>,<?php...?>";
     $str = explode(",", $value);
     foreach ($str as $option) 
     {
        echo "<li>".$option."</li>";
     }
  ?>
</ul>
```

I have following values but when I explode and show in form of list then all tags are not showing. So, How can I show all tags in list? Please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly display the tags, because by doing so, the page will "Execute" the tag. As example, `<script>` tag will be see as tags for Javascript and the HTML page will not display it.
What you need to do is to "encode" the tags first before displaying.

For PHP you can do this using htmlentities() function. Read more here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Just wrap the `$value` variable with htmlentities() function like following:

```
<ul>
  <?php
    $value = "<script>...</script>,<?php>...</?>,<&>...</&>,<?php...?>";
    $str = explode(",", htmlentities($value));
    foreach ($str as $option) 
    {
       echo "<li>".$option."</li>";
    }
  ?>
</ul>
```